# How to sort a list first by date and then by time in Python?

Tags: python-3.x, sorting, datetime, python-datetime

I have a list that contains DateTime objects that has come from database. I need to first sort it by date and take the latest date, for the latest date I need to take the first entry i.e. the oldest entry. Example, below is my list :

```py
import datetime

values = [datetime.datetime(2019, 2, 6, 10, 30, 28, 970000),
          datetime.datetime(2019, 2, 6, 10, 30, 31, 308000),
          datetime.datetime(2019, 2, 21, 14, 7, 42, 111000),
          datetime.datetime(2019, 2, 21, 14, 7, 59, 160000),
          datetime.datetime(2019, 2, 21, 14, 8, 12, 143000),
          datetime.datetime(2019, 2, 21, 14, 8, 15, 234000)]
```

I have entries for 6-feb and 21-feb. I need the first(oldest) entry for 21st Feb that is `datetime.datetime(2019, 2, 21, 14, 7, 42, 111000)`. I have tried using sorted(list) but since my value is somewhere falling in middle, it is not helping me.

What is the best way in Python to get that ?

Answer (score 0):

Using `itertools.groupby`

**Ex:**

```
import datetime
from itertools import groupby

data = [datetime.datetime(2019, 2, 6, 10, 30, 28, 970000), datetime.datetime(2019, 2, 6, 10, 30, 31, 308000), datetime.datetime(2019, 2, 21, 14, 7, 42, 111000), datetime.datetime(2019, 2, 21, 14, 7, 59, 160000), datetime.datetime(2019, 2, 21, 14, 8, 12, 143000), datetime.datetime(2019, 2, 21, 14, 8, 15, 234000)]
new_data = [list(v) for _, v in groupby(sorted(data), lambda x: x.strftime("%Y%m%d"))]       #GroupBy YearMonthDay
print(new_data[-1][0])   #latest date, first entry
```

**Output:**

```
2019-02-21 14:07:42.111000
```